# Fatching result from MySql in multidimensional array

Tags: php, pdo

i want to fetch photos from database in multidimensional array,so i can further use array_column function.
I have code:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM photos WHERE img_navigacija_id=2";
$result=$db->query($sql);

while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$rows[]=$row;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($rows[0]);
echo "</pre>";
}
```

Which brings me array like this:

```
Array
(
[id] => 117
[name] => 0012.jpg
[size] => 103141
[type] => image/jpeg
[date] => 2014-12-01 16:56:58
[img_navigacija_id] => 2
)
Array
(
[id] => 118
[name] => 0023.jpg
[size] => 101014
[type] => image/jpeg
[date] => 2014-12-01 16:57:05
[img_navigacija_id] => 2
)
Array
(
[id] => 119
[name] => 0035.jpg
[size] => 54304
[type] => image/jpeg
[date] => 2014-12-01 16:57:12
[img_navigacija_id] => 2
)
```

But i would like to have multidimensional array like this:

```
Array
(
     Array(
     [id] => 117
     [name] => 0012.jpg
     [size] => 103141
     [type] => image/jpeg
     [date] => 2014-12-01 16:56:58
     [img_navigacija_id] => 2
     ),
     Array(
     [id] => 117
     [name] => 0012.jpg
     [size] => 103141
     [type] => image/jpeg
     [date] => 2014-12-01 16:56:58
     [img_navigacija_id] => 2
    ),
    Array(
     [id] => 117
     [name] => 0012.jpg
     [size] => 103141
     [type] => image/jpeg
     [date] => 2014-12-01 16:56:58
     [img_navigacija_id] => 2
    ),
    Array
    (
   [id] => 117
   [name] => 0012.jpg
   [size] => 103141
   [type] => image/jpeg
   [date] => 2014-12-01 16:56:58
   [img_navigacija_id] => 2
   )
)
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: `var_dump($rows);` **after** the `while`, it should be in the desired format already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM photos WHERE img_navigacija_id=2";
 $result=$db->query($sql);

 while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $rows[]=$row;
 }
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($rows);
 echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

you are doing it ok. just put `print_r($rows);` after loop.

and init array `$rows = Array()` just before the loop.